# Magento 2 composer install

Tags: magento2

Anybody do a successful install of magento 2 only via composer ?
I found a nice article here : http://magenticians.com/installing-magento-2-composer
but sadly it's outdated. I tried it and I get errors :

```
The requested package magento/community-edition could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

Tried to change package to project-community-edition and got

```
Installation request for magento/project-community-edition *@dev -> satisfiable by magento/project-community-edition[dev-master].

magento/project-community-edition dev-master requires zendframework/zend-stdlib 2.0.3 -> no matching package found."
```

Comment: the new version work ok. but the installer is not working ok https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/706

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `composer.json` from [magenticians](http://magenticians.com/installing-magento-2-composer) is not up to date anymore. The following `composer.json` does work as of today, tested with Ubuntu 14.04

```
{   "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "magento/project-community-edition": "*@dev"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/magento/magento2.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

You  will need a GitHub account (because of rate limiting issues) and the `git` command line utility installed.

Comment: composer.json is updated with each release, so you must have your composer up to date, try composer update before composer install

Answer (score 0):

I have two methods for installing Magento 2 with Sample Data and with database by composer in "developer mode" on terminal.

---

#### 1 - Magento2 Install with Sample Data in developer mode on terminal

- Copy composer.json in root folder project

  ```
  wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2-community-edition/master/composer.json
  ```
- Change Magento2 Version from 2.0.2 to 2.0.7 or last version 
  => https://goo.gl/rk9bYK
- Run commands in terminal without sudo

  - Magento2 download

    ```
    composer install
    ```
  - Add Magento2 Sample Data in composer

    ```
    php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
    ```
  - Add credential for Username and Password -> https://goo.gl/9eyOE0
  - Magento2 Sample Data Download

    ```
    composer update
    ```
  - Magento2 set permisions

    ```
    chmod -R 0777 var/
    chmod -R 0777 pub/static
    chmod -R 0777 pub/media/
    chmod -R 0777 app/etc/
    ```
  - Magento2 Install with Sample Data in terminal

    ```
    php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://domain.com/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=database --db-user=root --db-password=root --admin-firstname=FirstName --admin-lastname=LastName --admin-email=email@email.com--admin-user=admin --admin-password=pass --language=en_US --backend-frontname=admin --use-sample-data --magento-init-params=“MAGE_MODE=developer”
    ```

---

#### 2 - Magento2 Install with Sample Data in developer mode on terminal

- Copy composer.json in root folder project

  ```
  wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2-community-edition/master/composer.json
  ```
- Change Magento2 Version from2.0.2 to 2.0.7 or last version => https://goo.gl/rk9bYK
- Run commands in terminal without sudo

  - Magento2 download

    ```
    composer install
    ```
  - Magento2 Install

    - Install on browser
    - OR
    - Install on terminal

      ```
      php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://domain.com/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=database --db-user=root --db-password=root --admin-firstname=FirstName --admin-lastname=LastName --admin-email=email@email.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=pass --language=en_US --backend-frontname=admin --magento-init-params=“MAGE_MODE=developer”
      ```
  - Add Magento2 Sample Data in composer

    ```
    php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
    ```
  - Add credential for Username and Password -> https://goo.gl/9eyOE0
  - Magento2 Sample Data Download

    ```
    composer update
    ```
  - Magento2 set permisions

    ```
    chmod -R 0777 var/
    chmod -R 0777 pub/static
    chmod -R 0777 pub/media/
    chmod -R 0777 app/etc/
    ```
  - Magento2 Sample Data install

    ```
    php bin/magento setup:upgrade
    ```
  - Magento2 deploy static content

    ```
    find pub/static \! -name '.htaccess' -delete
    php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
    php bin/magento cache:clean
    ```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this article- https://webscoot.io/blog/install-magento-2/

It covers all installation methods in a simplified manner. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you have some different errors maybe best way is

```
 composer install --no-suggest -o --ignore-platform-reqs --prefer-source
```

if you use dockergento than

```
dockergento  composer install --no-suggest -o --ignore-platform-reqs --prefer-source
```