# Can't run magento 2.2.3 on localhost via WAMP

Tags: magento2

i try to install **magento 2.2.3** in localhost w**amp 3.1.3** `/www` directory but wizard wont start.

I try `127.0.0.1/magento` but give me **500 Internal Server Error**.

Any suggestion?

Comment: follow http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/zip_install.html  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/web/install-web.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 composer install](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41591/magento-2-composer-install)

Comment: Please check my answer it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `wamp->apache` and open `httpd.conf` file

Remove **#** from

> LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so

(Enable this)

now **restart** wamp and try

Comment: I removed but noting happen ...This site can’t be reached .....ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: Please delete cahce folder and try it should work @AngelTerziisky

Comment: Where is the cahce folder?

Comment: var/cache @AngelTerziisky

Comment: don't have it only .htasses and .regenerate in var dir

Comment: ok now check your wamp is active if yes then run your 127.0.0.1/magento url @AngelTerziisky

Comment: Its ok. Please upvote this answer @AngelTerziisky

Comment: this fix worked. saved my day